# Table height issue ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

Trying to print a table with 100% width and 100% height in table_details.php as

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1" style="text-align:center">
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And its working fine as:

[image]

But when I am trying to print table through ajax page, such as table_details.php calling from table.php.

table.php

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var key_val = 'test';
  var dataString = 'key_val=' + key_val;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "table_details.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
        $('body').html(html);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

But table not taking height. Its printing like:

[image]

Whats wrong with my logic?

Comment: For 100% height to be implemented all parent elements must have a height set too, right up to the `<html>` tag. This example is what you're currently doing: https://jsfiddle.net/m4vsqynp/, and this is with height set on the parents: https://jsfiddle.net/m4vsqynp/1/

Comment: But why the scrolling is coming

Comment: That's due to the default `margin` added to the `body`. You can remove it: https://jsfiddle.net/m4vsqynp/2/

Answer (score 0):

Give height `100%` to your `body` and `html`.